# How to fix Parser Error in gherkin when I write the code with ruby for automate test

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I created `search.feature` and `search.rb` files to build automatic testing. After that, I run with the command on the terminal and get an error. How to fix it?

I've tried on Linux subsystem on windows with `Ruby 2.6.1` and `Cucumber 3.1.2`

This is the code of *search.feature* file :

```
    The google homepage allows user to perform a search.

    Scenario Outline: Users can perform a search on Google
        Given I open the Google search page
        When I search for "<search>"
        Then I should see the results page

    Examples :
        | search    |
        | baju      |
        | bola      |
        | indonesia |
```

And this is the code of *search.rb* file :

```
Given /^I open the Google search page$/ do
    visit "/"
end

Given /^I search for "(.*?)"$/ do |search_term|
    @page_search = SearchPage.new
    @page_search.search(search_term)
end

Then /^I should see the results page$/ do
    expect(@page_search).to have_search_field
end
```

After that, when I run the command on the terminal I get an error like this :

```
➜  cucumber-native cucumber
features/scenario/search/search.feature: Parser errors:
(9:2): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ExamplesLine, #ScenarioLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Examples :' (Cucumber::Core::Gherkin::ParseError)
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:34:in `rescue in document'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:28:in `document'/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:30:in `block in parse'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `each'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:21:in `compile'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:75:in `run!'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/oimtrust/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Error that you faced must be because you have space between `Examples` and `:` (colon)

Answer (score 1):

`Examples` section must be nested within `Scenario`

```
Scenario Outline: Users can perform a search on Google
    Given I open the Google search page
    When I search for "<search>"
    Then I should see the results page

    Examples:
        | search    |
        | baju      |
        | bola      |
        | indonesia |
```

Comment: Still the same. I have a structure of code like this picture  http://prntscr.com/mlvivn